# iMovie crashes on double clicking

Tags: crash, big-sur, imovie

1. Drag an image onto the timeline.
2. Move the mouse cursor to the end of the image until you see the cursor changes to something like this `<-|->`
3. Then double click, instantly iMovie crashes.

I haven't used iMovie for a while, after I downloaded it and started to use it for just 1 minute, then I have no words on this piece of crap.

Not sure how such a basic thing passed their stupid quality assurance...

Anyone has the same issue?

Version 10.2.2 on Big Sur

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What filetype is the image? You could try to change its filetype with any photo software and try again. Have you rebooted your machine, reset SMC and NVRAM/PRAM? Also what happens in safe mode? Also, have you tried deleting iMove and reinstalling it? Have you tried this in different projects in iMovie? Does it happen for all image types and even video clips?

Comment: it's a jpeg file.  Brand new project in iMovie latest version.

Comment: Ok great, but could you please try and test the other things I mentioned and then edit that info into your question? Otherwise people will have to dig through comments to find more info. That double click opens precision editor for me. What happens when you go to `view` -> `precision editor`? (I also tried it with a .jpg, no problem for me)